# What version of CUDA introduced cuSolverRF?

Tags: cuda, cusolver

I have access to a machine with CUDA 7.5, but I think it is missing the cuSolverRF library.

The current documentation marked as version DU-06709-001_v8.0 says "In addition cuSolver provides a new refactorization library useful for solving sequences of matrices with a shared sparsity pattern" presumably the cuSolverRF library, suggesting that it was introduced in 8.0, but I can't find any release notes confirming this.

Comment: [cuda sample doc](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#new-features-in-cuda-toolkit-7-5) says the example `7_CUDALibraries/cuSolverRf` is added in 7.5. Therefore I guess it is at least introduced in 7.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the cuSolver library [was introduced in CUDA 7](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/parallel-direct-solvers-with-cusolver-batched-qr/).

the  cuSolverRF features of cuSolver were introduced during the CUDA 7 release cycle. i.e. they have been part of cuSolver since day 1.

[Here](https://www.clear.rice.edu/comp422/resources/cuda/pdf/CUSOLVER_Library.pdf) is the CUDA 7 cuSolver reference manual supporting this assertion.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed.  The 7.0 docs even include that same sentence: "cuSolver provides a new refactorization library useful for solving sequences of matrices with a shared sparsity
pattern."